# How can I insert into another table selecting from another ignoring the data type

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am running the query below and I am getting the error shown

```
core=# INSERT INTO transactionp SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE posting_date>'2021-08-17';
ERROR:  column "balance" is of type u_money but expression is of type u_datetime
LINE 1: INSERT INTO transactionp SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE pos...
                                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of the dreaded `select *` and not specifying target columns for the insert. Both are considered "code smell" and should be avoided.

The error message suggests that the order of columns is different in the source and target tables (they are matched by *position* not by name)

To fix this, specify column names in both parts: the INSERT and the SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO transactionp (balance, some_column, another_column, ...) 
SELECT some_balance, column_one, column_two, ...
FROM transaction 
WHERE posting_date>'2021-08-17';
```